# How i eexec gobblin with Docker

Tags: docker, hadoop, gobblin

I want to create 2 Docker containers. One with Hadood 2.7.2 and the other one with the last Gobblin realise. But I need to Launch the job to run on Hadoop
"$HADOOP_BIN_DIR/hadoop jar \" from the gobblin container. And I always recived the same message, " this isn't a file or directory". I dont Know the way to launch a command throught the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance of Goblin is isolated from Hadoop instance and you can not get access to Hadoop container files primary. Instead this you should to use `volumes`. Example:

```
docker run -v $HADOOP_BIN_DIR/hadoop.jar --name hadoop Hadoop
docker run --volumes-from hadoop Goblin
```

You can read more information about volumes here https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/